# Wrapping event with Reactive Extensions when there are Start and Stop methods

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive

I'm attempting to wrap a device class with an `IObservable`. Without Rx its used like this:

```
device.IncomingData += data => { /* do something with float[] data */ };
device.Start(500);
// Something...
device.Stop();
```

So far I've got a wrapper class like below, which tracks how many observers are using the stream and stops and starts it accordingly.

Is there not a built-in way to track the observers with Rx?

```
private class ObservableWrapper
{
  private int _observers;

  public ObservableStreamer(IDevice device)
  {
    Stream = Observable.FromEvent<float[]>(
      e =>
        {
          device.IncomingData += e;
          int obs = Interlocked.Increment(ref _observers);

          if (obs < 2)
            device.Start();
        },
      e =>
        {
          device.IncomingData -= e;
          int obs = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _observers);

          if (obs < 1)
            device.Stop();
        });
  }

  public IObservable<float[]> Stream { get; private set; }
} 

var wrap = new ObservableWrapper(device);
wrap.Stream.Subscribe(data => { /* do something with float[] data */ });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building a custom observable, don't bother adding ref counting or connection sharing. If you need those features you can add them with `RefCount` and `Publish`, respectively. You should also almost never have a reason to implement `I(Connectable)Observable` yourself.

As for your specific use case, it could be a reasonably simple extension method:

```
public static DeviceExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<float[]> AsObservable(this Device device)
    {
        return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<float[]>(obs =>
        {
            IDisposable disposable = Observable.FromEvent<float[]>(
                e => device.IncomingData += e,
                e => device.IncomingData -= e
                )
                .Finally(device.Stop)
                .Subscribe(obs);

            device.Start();

            return disposable;
        });
    }
}
```

And now you can use it like this:

```
IObservable<float[]> observableData = device.AsObservable()
    .RefCount(); // If you need ref counting

observableData.Subscribe(data => {});

observableData.Subscribe(data => {});
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you have actually maps better to the lesser used [IConnectableObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211887%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).  The Connect method would call Start and return a disposable that calls Stop.  The Subscribe method would forward to the Observable.FromEvent (without all the ref-counting).  You can then use [RefCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211664%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on that to turn it back into a regular IObservable.  As with your current implementation, you have to use the same instance for all subscriptions or the counting won't work right.

For example (uncompiled code incoming):

```
class ObservableDevice : IConnectableObservable
{
    public ObservableDevice(IDevice device)
    {
        _device = device;
        //not strictly necessary to cache this, but this way you only
        //create it once
        _stream = Observable.FromEvent<...>(...);
    }

    private IDevice _device;
    private IObservable _stream;

    public IDisposable Connect()
    {
        //it's up to you if you want/need to guard against multiple starts
        _device.Start();
        return Disposable.Create(() => { _device.Stop(); });
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver observer)
    {
        //error checking if you want, or just defer to 
        //_stream.Subscribe's error checking
        return _stream.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```